# Relating $f(\mathrm{Var}[X])$ to $\mathrm{Var}[f(X)]$ for Positive, Increasing, and Concave $f(X)$

Tags: variance, poisson-distribution, probability-inequalities, convex

The arrival of photons at a pixel in an image sensor is a Poisson distributed random variable such that the input can be modeled as a Poisson r.v. $X\sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

Since the input is Poisson, the mean and variance are equal such that

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathrm{Var}[X]}=1
\end{equation}

Now when the photon input is passed through a linear image sensor (camera) to produce a digital output, we can treat this as a linear transformation of $X$ such that the output, $Y$ is $Y=X/g$.

In the case of this linear sensor, I can extract the `conversion gain', i.e. number of photons required to produce a digital output of one, represented as $g$ in units of (photons/digital#), as

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y]}{\mathrm{Var}[Y]}=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X/g]}{\mathrm{Var}[X/g]}=\frac{\frac{1}{g}\mathbb{E}[X]}{\frac{1}{g^2}\mathrm{Var}[X]}=g
\end{equation}

However, now consider a sensor where the conversion gain depends linearly on the input, e.g. $Y=X/(aX+b)$ where $a>0$ and $b>0$. This means that the gain is an increasing function of signal $g(x)=ax+b$.

In the case of this non-linear sensor, the gain can no longer be found from the ratio of the mean to variance at the output

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y]}{\mathrm{Var}[Y]}\neq g(x)
\end{equation}

In fact, the measured conversion gain is found to be larger than the actual conversion gain for any input signal level.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y]}{\mathrm{Var}[Y]}> g(x)
\end{equation}

Part of the explanation for this is Jensen's inequality which states that for a increasing concave transformation of some random input $X$, i.e. $Y=f(X)$:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\leq f(\mathbb{E}[X])
\end{equation}

In my case $Y=X/(aX+b)$ is in fact a increasing concave function meaning that the measured mean at the output is less than the transformed mean of the input. ***Since we know the measured gain at the output is overestimated and the measured mean is underestimated, this implies that the measured variance is even more underestimated than the mean***.

How can I prove this or mathematically write this? Is there a generalization of Jensen's inequality for the variance? Can I show exactly why the gain is overestimated in this example?

Comment: If $g$ is a function of $X$, it has just changed dramatically from a constant to a random variable, i.e. a non-constant function. Then, how could it remain equal to the ratio of two constant quantities (mean/variance)? I don't see room for a "deeper" understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no relation between the two quantities $f(\text{Var}[X])$ and $\text{Var}[f(X)]$ for concave $f$. Here are the examples to demonstrate this:

- Ex 1: Suppose random variable $X$ has the pmf: $p_X(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $p_X(4) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. We get $\text{Var}[f(X)] = 1$ and $f(\text{Var}[X]) = f(4) = 2$. So, $\text{Var}[f(X)] < f(\text{Var}[X])$.
- Ex 2: Suppose random variable $X$ is same as before i.e. it has the pmf: $p_X(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $p_X(4) = \frac{1}{2}$, but $f$ changed to $f(x) = \sqrt{x} - 100$. Note that $\text{Var}[f(X)] = 1$ still, but now $f(\text{Var}[X]) = f(4) = 2-100=-98$. So, $\text{Var}[f(X)] > f(\text{Var}[X])$.

Comment: That's a good point.  In my example I was not as specific as I should have been.  I am interested in the case of increasing, positive, concave functions.  Does a relationship exist under that class of functions?

Comment: Ex 3: Suppose $X$ has a pmf: $p_X(0) =p_X(4) = \frac{1}{2}$, but $f(x)$ is $f(x) = 100\sqrt{x}$. $\text{Var}[f(X)]$ is equal to $10000$, but $f(\text{Var}[X]) = 200$. Therefore, $\text{Var}[f(X)] > f(\text{Var}[X])$. Check that in examples 1 and 3, $f$ is increasing positive and concave.